# Trying to mark first encounter in every group pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df with 5 columns:

[image: photo example in excel]

What i'm trying to do is mark value of first customer interaction after talking to human in every specific group.

Hopefully the outcome would be like this:

[image: this output]

What I have tried is shifting type column to put previous row in front of type to check if its customer and prev row is human. However, I can't figure out a grouping option to get min index for each group for each occurrence.

Comment: Interesting problem! Will you please provide your input data as text, not an image, so I can copy/paste it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
k = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('group').apply(lambda g: (g['type'].eq('customer') & g['type'].shift(1).eq('human')).pipe(lambda x: [x.idxmax(), x[::-1].idxmax()])).tolist())

df['First'] = ''
df['Last'] = ''

df.loc[k[1], 'First'] = 'F'
df.loc[k[1], 'Last'] = 'L'
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   group      type First Last
0      x       bot           
1      x  customer           
2      x       bot           
3      x  customer           
4      x     human           
5      x  customer     F     
6      x     human           
7      x  customer          L
8      y       bot           
9      y  customer           
10     y       bot           
11     y  customer           
12     y     human           
13     y  customer     F     
14     y     human           
15     y  customer          L
16     z       bot           
17     z  customer           
18     z       bot           
19     z  customer           
20     z     human           
21     z  customer     F     
22     z     human           
23     z  customer          L
24     z  customer           
25     z  customer
```

Comment: Sorry about the format not sure how to add it like you did , but your code works so perfect , Thank you so much i was hoping to get a quick breakdown of the idea of how it works if possible (what i noticed is that you created a df with first and last pos for type and added a condition for it to have human before it then i missed the concept of this .pipe(lambda x: [x.idxmax(), x[::-1].idxmax()])).tolist()) would love to know about the idea behind it if possible) thanks again so much